# Export custom object to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm quite new to powershell and struggling with outputting data to a CSV file.
I have a larger code piece but created the below small working example that contains the issue:

```
$results = @()
$tmp_avs = @('tmp', 'tmp2')
$hostname = 'hostname'
$results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{Hostname=$hostname; avs=$tmp_avs})
$res = $results | ? {$_.avs.Count -gt 0} | Format-Table

$res | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "test.csv"
```

When printing the `$res` object above in PowerShell I get the output:

```
avs         Hostname
---         --------
{tmp, tmp2} hostname
```

That is also the output I would like to receive in the CSV file, but currently I get something like this:

```
"ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd","pageHeaderEntry","pageFooterEntry","autosizeInfo","shapeInfo","groupingEntry"
"033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280",,,,"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo",
"9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
"4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df",,,,,
"cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c",,,,,
```

Is there a possibility to export the `$res` object in a proper CSV format?

EDIT:
I removed the `Format-Table` now, which results in the following in the CSV format:

```
"avs","Hostname"
"System.Object[]","hostname"
```

There is `System.Object[]` written instead of the values?

Comment: Remove `Format-Table`.

Comment: to clarify what Ansgar said, `format-table` actually converts your data into a different object with data related to the table format. `export-csv` and other cmdlets prefer to operate on the "raw" `psobject` you generated.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36260409/1630171).

Comment: I removed the `format-table` now and it looks more like it, but I receive a "System.Object[]" were the actual values should be!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are an array. If you run `$tmp_avs.ToString()`, you will also get `System.Object[]`

To resolve, replace `avs=$tmp_avs` with `avs=$($tmp_avs -join " ")` where  is the joining character between elements of your array. It converts the array to a string.

**Code:**

```
$results = @()
$tmp_avs = @('tmp', 'tmp2')
$hostname = 'hostname'
$results = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{Hostname=$hostname; avs=$($tmp_avs -join " ")})
$res = $results | ? {$_.avs.Count -gt 0} 
$res | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "test.csv"
```

**Output:**

```
avs,Hostname
tmp tmp2, hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to see System.object[], but a comma separated list, you could convert your array to a string, so this can be outputted correctly in CSV.

Try adding `$tmp_avs = $tmp_avs -join ";"` to your script below the line `$tmp_avs = @('tmp', 'tmp2')`.